# error 0x80004005 when install bash on ubuntu on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I get the error `0x80004005` when I install bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10.OS insider preview china.

How do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: That error code is "access denied". It's caused by trying to write files to the Windows\System32 folder. You don't have sufficient privileges to write to that folder. That folder belongs to the OS, not you. Stop trying to do so, install to a different folder where you have privileges, and add that new folder to your PATH.

Comment: I run cmd as administer。I install to other is also failure.The same mistake

Answer (score 3):

I've also encounter the problem. 
It's because the Microsoft account will create Chinese user folder name if you sign-in with your Microsoft account first time. The extracting process seems not work well on DBCS folder.

I've create a new local admin account in English and then try to sign-in Microsoft Account again, the problem has been solved.

Comment: Put simply, The user home folder must have a english name?

Answer (score 1):

You must use an English name for your home folder, this is because bash on windows  currently only supports ASCII characters. I had the same issue with Cyrillic and I fixed it by making a new account with English.

Answer (score 0):

### If creating an account with English letters didn't fix the issue, then I'd suggest you to try out this approach.

- **Run** `Windows + R`
- Type `SystemPropertiesAdvanced` & Hit **Enter**
- Click `settings` in the **`performance`** group.

  [image]
- Select **Change** option in **Advanced** tab, then **deselect** the automatically manage paging file size for all drives option.
- Select `custom size` and enter `800` for **initial size**, `1024` for **maximum size.**

  [image]
- Apply changes and restart.

Comment: Thanks for that tweak, it didn't change anything for me though.Still error 0x80004005 after restarting and trying again.

Answer (score -1):

In my case this error disappeared after freeing some space on disk (<1GiB was not enough).